# Formula for $\sum_{i = 1}^n k^n$

Tags: summation, exponentiation, exponential-sum

I know from my calculator the answer is $\sum_{i = 1}^n k^n$ = $\frac{k^{n+1}-k}{k - 1}$. I'd just like help understanding why.

Comment: Just check that $k^n -1 = (k-1)(\sum_{i=0}^{k=n-1} k^i)$

Comment: Your index is $i$ so $\sum_{i=1}^nk^n=nk^n$.   You probably mean $\sum_{k=1}^nk^n$.  Or did you mean $\sum_{i=1}^Nk^i$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because 
$$(1-k)(1+k^2+k^3+\dots+k^n)=(1+k^2+k^3+\dots+k^n)-(k+k^2+k^3+\dots+k^{n+1})=1-k^{n+1}$$